# Finding the most frequently occurring element in multiple roaring bitmaps

Tags: algorithm, bitmap, roaring-bitset

I have n number of roaring bitmaps, and I want to find out which element is most occurring in these n roaring bitmaps. Also, find out the count. What is the best and most efficient way to do this? I have millions of records in one bitmap, and traversing and storing the results in a hashmap is not feasible. Additionally, I am looking for elements that occur in more than n/2 bitmaps

I have tried Boyer-Moore Majority algorithms, but it is inefficient because I don't want to traverse all the elements.

Comment: Yes, in single roaring bitmap, i might have millions of elements.

Comment: https://roaringbitmap.org/

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. You say you want to find the elements that occur in more than n/2 bitmaps, but you don't want to traverse all the elements. How in the world do you expect to determine the most common elements if you don't look at all of them?

Comment: We can ignore high cardinality sets and find the top k occurring element in the remaining sets. Once we get the top k elements, we can check those top k elements present in ignored sets. #justthinking